# Kubernetes services sometimes unreachable

Tags: service, kubernetes, kops

I have a cluster kubernetes v1.5.2 installed with `kops` and using the `weave` network plugin. I noticed that sometimes my kubernetes services get unreachable from within a pod on my cluster.

I went through the entire article about troubleshooting services: https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/cluster-troubleshooting/ I can confirm that everything is performing as expected but sometimes it's not (this is a curl from within a pod of the cluster trying to reach a service using its IP address. This service is backed by 5 endpoints, all up and running):

```
$> curl 100.65.135.200 -vv
* Rebuilt URL to: 100.65.135.200/
*   Trying 100.65.135.200...
* connect to 100.65.135.200 port 80 failed: No route to host
* Failed to connect to 100.65.135.200 port 80: No route to host
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 100.65.135.200 port 80: No route to host
```

That's the first time I setup a cluster with `kops` and `weave` and that's the first time I see this. If anyone has a clue to debug this, that would be awesome !!

### Update

- kube proxy is correctly registering my service: `I0210 23:09:41.070508       6 proxier.go:472] Adding new service "my_app/my_app:http" at 100.65.135.200:80/TCP`
- My pod IPs doesn't overlap with the cluster's

I'm seeing some weird logs however on the `weave-kube` container on the 2 nodes of my clusters:

```
INFO: 2017/02/11 12:14:10.959122 Discovered remote MAC b2:3e:c7:99:16:de at ce:7d:9f:95:66:fb(ip-172-20-55-245)
ERRO: 2017/02/11 12:14:10.959348 Captured frame from MAC (b2:3e:c7:99:16:de) to (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) associated with another peer ce:7d:9f:95:66:fb(ip-172-20-55-245)
ERRO: 2017/02/11 12:14:39.140186 Captured frame from MAC (06:b7:eb:e7:fa:0e) to (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) associated with another peer c2:58:a0:4e:b2:ff(ip-172-20-75-108)
ERRO: 2017/02/11 12:15:52.273667 Captured frame from MAC (32:f9:43:24:68:ad) to (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) associated with another peer c2:58:a0:4e:b2:ff(ip-172-20-75-108)
ERRO: 2017/02/11 12:16:56.686643 Captured frame from MAC (c2:58:a0:4e:b2:ff) to (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) associated with another peer c2:58:a0:4e:b2:ff(ip-172-20-75-108)
ERRO: 2017/02/11 12:16:56.686969 Captured frame from MAC (ce:7d:9f:95:66:fb) to (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) associated with another peer ce:7d:9f:95:66:fb(ip-172-20-55-245)
ERRO: 2017/02/11 12:16:56.687002 Captured frame from MAC (72:85:2b:19:65:b9) to (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) associated with another peer c2:58:a0:4e:b2:ff(ip-172-20-75-108)
ERRO: 2017/02/11 12:16:56.687042 Captured frame from MAC (f2:1a:9e:d8:7f:a3) to (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) associated with another peer c2:58:a0:4e:b2:ff(ip-172-20-75-108)
```

Gonna investigate this

### Update 2

So these weaves errors was my problem. Apparently ethtool was required by weave and it was missing from my image. I updated the AMI to 1.5 and everything is now working as expected.

Comment: ethtool is not required by Weave Net, but it is required by Kubernetes.  If you don't have it, Kubernetes does something that is absolutely disastrous to Weave Net. I fixed this in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/36990

Answer (score 0):

> everything is performing as expected but sometimes it's not

It would be good to get some more detail to characterise this - is it one pod fails while others work, or all pods sometimes work and sometimes fail?

However, some additional things to check:

1. Are your virtual ethernet devices being disconnected from the bridge? See https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/issues/2601
2. Does your pod IP address space overlap the cluster IP address space?
3. Check 100.65.135.200 is mapped by kube-proxy (that part is described in https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/cluster-troubleshooting/)

The ultimate step is to look at the network packets - run `tcpdump -n -i weave` while you run the `curl` test; if you don't see anything there then run the dump on the pod's veth.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my question I think I'm seeing abnormal logs from weave